# Cross correlation for two non stationary time series

Tags: cross-correlation, stationarity

I have a dependent non-stationary time series and 4 independent non-stationary time series. Because of small sample size (n=11) I couldn't use regression for prediction but I want just report correlation between dependent and each of independent time series. Is cross correlation usable for non-stationary time series? What value of cross-correlation show the high correlation?

Comment: Did you ever come to a conclusion about this?